# Add specific price Prestashop

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In the product page  I want to create a special div that display itselft with Jquery, in that page the client will find different options that he could add like an accesory, the question is: How I can add a specific price adding up : base price + specific price + combination price.
I was trying to modify product.js but it didn't change anything, I'm not expert in prestashop core, Then as many information you could let me will be very gratefull.
Thank you.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You can add a specific price and combination price and it would be visible in product page with no modifications.

Answer (score 0):

On the product page there are various JS variable for price and combinations are already there.

So you can simply create a module with a hook (`hookDisplayLeftColumnProduct`, `hookDisplayRightColumnProduct` etc.) on product page to render your JS code on the product page and through that code you can achieve what you want (also using the price JS variables on product page).

```
public function hookDisplayLeftColumnProduct()
{
    // Render Your tpl here
}
```